# An upgrade from 'disco' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04, 19.04

I am very beginner, I want to upgrade Ubuntu 19.04 to 20,  I do command below:

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

source repository is http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu  and upgrade behavior is normal.

I think the above commands are run without problems. result after any command is:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but after run do-release-upgrade , I can not upgrade and display :

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,337 kB]
Fetched 1,338 kB in 0s (0 B/s)
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg'
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade

An upgrade from 'disco' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool.
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Sun Jul 19 03:33:35 2020) ===
```

What should I do?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is now unsupported. I suggest you perform a fresh installation of 20.04

Comment: You can't jump from 19.04 to 20.04 [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading).

Comment: ok,thak you very much

Comment: The *fully tested* way of upgrading is either from one release to the next (ie. 19.04 to 19.10), OR if you are on a LTS you have the option of the next release (ie. 18.04 to 18.10) OR jumping from 18.04 to the next LTS release, ie. 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS. 19.04 wasn't a LTS so the *fully tested* path is to 19.10. You don't need to start again via re-install (use 'something-else' & don't format).